How to Get the JWT Token from the Cookies using Rust Warp?
I am writing API code Cookie based Authentication using the rust warp. I was already write the code of user register and login code But I don't know to how to get that JWT token from the cookies. My code details in my Github link
I want get the JWT token from My browser cookies...

Please create a self contained question. Everything that isn't is out of scope for [so].

The Warp tests provide useful info here.
To get the string value of a JWT from a cookie name "foo":
let foo_cookie_filter = warp::cookie::<String>("foo");
let jwt = req.filter(&foo_cookie_filter).await.unwrap();

